# Flask blog, only want one user to be able to post

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, admin, blogs

I'm creating a blog using Flask and Python and I have a problem. I only want one user to be able to post. In my HTML for post I tried writing

```
 {% if current_user == default_user1 %}

   .....code for creating a new post....

 {% else %}
        <h2>Only Admin can create new posts</h2>
 {% endif %}
```

In my database I created the user like this

```
default_user1 = User(username='Admin',
                         email='default@test.com',
                         profile='Admin',
                         password=hashed_password)
    db.session.add(default_user1)
```

But when I try to post something while logged in on default_user1 it says "Only Admin can create post". Do you know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 objects in python need not be similar to each other, even if they have the same content

consider the code

```py
class Abc:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

a = Abc("Arjun")
b = Abc("Arjun")
print(a == b)
```

this will print `False`,

solution :
compare via the username

change

`{% if current_user == default_user1 %}`

to

`{% if current_user.username == "Admin" %}`